# One storyboard, two controllers

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Let's say we have two views in the app that look identical. 
Both views, however, have different logic (data source etc) that we would like to separate.
Is it possible for two different controllers to use the same storyboard?
If not, what is the best solution to the above problem?

Comment: I don't see a problem, why not as long as their classes are different

Answer (score 0):

With a storyboard it could be a little bit complicate because of the outlet and action connections. But you can put the view into a XIB/NIB file and load it from your different controllers with the appropriate initializer.

Answer (score 0):

`Storyboard` is a `Interface Builder` which building interface. If you have the same view, then they can use the same view controller. And then give different instance a different data source.

For example: you have a class named `MyViewController` in your storybard with storyboardid=`storyboardid` which having a label. You initiate two controller in the same way:

```
let vc1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardid")
let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardid")
```

vc1 and vc2 looks exactly the same, but you can use different `data source` like this:

```
vc1.title = "title of vc1"
vc2.title = "title of vc2"
```

So you define view once and `have different logic (data source etc) that we would like to separate`